# SQL Query is slow when ORDER BY statement added

Tags: sql-server, performance

I have a table `[Documents]` with the following columns:

```
Name (string)
Status (string)
DateCreated [datetime]
```

This table has around 1 million records. All three of these columns have an index (a single index for each one).

When I run this query:

```
select top 50 *  
from [Documents] 
where (Name = 'None' OR Name is null OR Name = '') 
  and Status = 'New';
```

Execution is really fast (300 ms.)

If I run the same query but with the `ORDER BY` clause, it's really slow (3000 ms)

```
select top 50 *  
from [Documents] 
where (Name = 'None' OR Name is null OR Name = '') 
  and Status = 'New'
order by DateCreated;
```

I understand that its searching in another index (`DateCreated`), but should it really be that much slower? If so, why? Anything I can do to speed this query up (a composite index)?

Thanks

BTW: All Indexes including `DateCreated` have really low fragmentation, in fact I ran a reorganize and it didn't change a thing.

Comment: Have you tried using the Index Tuning wizard?

Comment: The database is in Azure, can't run it against it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as why the query is slower, the query is required to return the rows "in order", so it either needs to do a sort, or it needs to use an index.

Using the index with a leading column of CreatedDate, SQL Server can avoid a sort. But SQL Server would also have to visit the pages in the underlying table to evaluate whether the row is to be returned, looking at the values in Status and Name columns.

If the optimizer chooses not to use the index with CreatedDate as the leading column, then it needs to first locate all of the rows that satisfy the predicates, and then perform a sort operation to get those rows in order. Then it can return the first fifty rows from the sorted set. (SQL Server wouldn't necessarily need to sort the entire set, but it would need to go through that whole set, and do sufficient sorting to guarantee that it's got the "first fifty" that need to be returned.

NOTE: I suspect you already know this, but to clarify: SQL Server honors the `ORDER BY` before the `TOP 50`.  If you wanted any 50 rows that satisfied the predicates, but not necessarily the 50 rows with the lowest values of DateCreated,you could restructure/rewrite your query, to get (at most) 50 rows, and then perform the sort of just those.

---

**A couple of ideas to improve performance**

Adding a composite index (as other answers have suggested) may offer some improvement, for example:

```
 ON Documents (Status, DateCreated, Name)
```

SQL Server might be able to use that index to satisfy the equality predicate on Status, and also return the rows in DateCreated order without a sort operation. SQL server may also be able to satisfy the predicate on Name from the index, limiting the number of lookups to pages in the underlying table, which it needs to do for rows to be returned, to get "all" of the columns for the row.

---

For SQL Server 2008 or later, I'd consider a filtered index... dependent on the cardinality of Status='New'  (that is, if rows that satisfy the predicate `Status='New'` is a relatively small subset of the table.

```
  CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX Documents_FIX 
  ON Documents (Status, DateCreated, Name)
  WHERE Status = 'New'
```

I would also modify the query to specify `ORDER BY Status, DateCreated, Name`

so that the order by clause matches the index, it doesn't really change the order that the rows are returned in.

---

As a more complicated  alternative, I would consider adding a persisted  computed column and adding a filtered index on that

```
  ALTER TABLE Documents
    ADD new_none_date_created AS
      CASE 
        WHEN Status = 'New' AND COALESCE(Name,'') IN ('','None') THEN DateCreated 
        ELSE NULL
      END
    PERSISTED
  ;  

  CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX Documents_FIXP 
  ON Documents (new_none_date_created)
  WHERE new_none_date_created IS NOT NULL
  ;
```

Then the query could be re-written:

```
  SELECT TOP 50 *
    FROM Documents
   WHERE new_none_date_created IS NOT NULL
   ORDER BY new_none_date_created 
  ;
```

---

Comment: Why "I would also modify the query to specify ORDER BY Status, DateCreated, Name." I understand that adding Status to the order statement will not change the order of the rows, but how will it improve the query?

Comment: Also, I didn't mention in the question, but my query is dynamically generated using Dynamic.Linq, so adding the persisted computed column is not really an option.... but thanks....

Comment: @pmeyer: i'd modify the `ORDER BY` clause to *exactly* match the order of the columns in the index, to increase the chance that SQL Server will use the index to return the rows in order, avoiding a SORT operation. But we'd really need to look at the EXPLAIN to see if the optimizer is using the index or not. (The optimizer *should* be smart enough to recognize that it can use the index to satisfy the order by, even if we just `ORDER BY DateCreated`. And including Name won't hurt anything. Making that change to the query is just something I would test, looking at EXPLAIN.

Comment: thanks for the help, between the composite index and the filtered index which one do you think would provide greater improvement?

Comment: Without the access plan and without statistics and expected cardinalities, we're just guessing. My guess is better performance by avoiding the sort operation, by returning rows in order from an index. For the query text as shown, my guess is the composite index "ON Documents(Status, DateCreated, Name)"  would give the biggest improvement. Adding the filter to that index would probably result in a much smaller index. But the filtered index wouldn't be a suitable as a replacement for the index on the singleton Status column.

Answer (score 1):

If `DateCreated` field means insertion time to table, you can create an integer id field and order by that integer field.

Comment: That's a good point, however I'm trying to figure out why my query is slow more than trying to fix it.  I could apply this same query to another datetime column and I would have the same issue...

Answer (score 0):

You need an index by 2 columns: (Name, DateCreated). The order of fields in the index is important. So, replace your index for just Name with a new index for two columns (Name, DateCreated).

Comment: Why only on the Name column and no on the Status column?

Comment: Let's think more on it.

Do you have any expectations how many rows can be with Status = 'New'?
Do you have any expectations how many rows can be with (Name = 'None' OR Name is null OR Name = '')?
What is your DateCreate, just date or date and time?
How may columns in the table?

Comment: (Name = 'None' OR Name is null OR Name = '') = 468076
Status = 'New' = 24559. I assume against name its better?

Comment: It is good to know statistics. The more unique value of indexed field, the better index works for query.
Try to create a new index for (Status, CreatedDate) (replacing index for Status only).

Comment: The table has lots of columns around 50 or so... any help appreciated @sergei-zinovyev

Comment: Well then... Name has more unique values than Status... it has more empty values but it still has way more unique values...

Comment: See, you have 2 level of filtering. By applying Stutus = New filter will have 25K records that needs to be filtered additinally and sorted. If you do by Name first then you have 468K records for another level of filtering. Does it make sense? If sql-server finds (Status, CreatedDate) index it wlll apply the first filter (Status) and then your sorted data (by CreatedDate) will be filtered second time by Name (Name = 'None' OR Name is null OR Name = '').